# Creating a python "applet" for ubuntu (gnome) utility panel

Tags: gnome, python, gtk, panel, applet

I'm interested in creating an applet for the gnome "utility panel" in python. I really don't even need any interactivity. I just want to display some text and have it change occasionally based on outside events. So, there would probably be a "loop" running that occasionally updates the text based on some conditions.

To be clear: by "utility panel" I mean the horizontal bar that sits at the top of a default ubuntu desktop installation (bionic beaver) that includes the date, volume controls, etc. Please correct my terminology if its' wrong. I would like to have an applet appear right along side the volume, network, battery widgets (or applets).

What is the *right* way to do this in python? I'd like to stick to standard gnome/gtk python API and not introduce any other dependencies or wrappers.